origami J-SHAPED t2
It's been a long time since I've posted an origami puzzle!
Fold the shape into a rectangle such that the rectangle is 2 layers thick everywhere. The red part is not included in the puzzle; the purple part is the puzzle.

Although solutions are not required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.
A puzzle for this type of orgami puzzle game made by Ωmega_3301, similar to this question.

Center edges of 3 squares diagonal folds:

 


intended! +1&accepted


 

logic:

 first notice that you can "solve" the curves by rolling the paper up into a cylinder along the x=y line.


 now we need to solve the top and bottom. since no matter how you "roll" the cylinder, the curves stay solved, we just have to collapse the cylinder into a 2d shape such that the ends can fold into a rectangle.

for anyone attempting my original puzzle pack (linked in the question), the spoilered logic is helpful for a lot of puzzles.
